# Using PHP pack() to Convert WKT into WKB

Tags: php, mysql, polygon, spatial, wkt

I'm using prepared statements to insert data into my database, problem is I'm not able to use

INSERT INTO table (polygon) VALUES (GeomFromText(POLYGON((?,?,?,?,?,?))))

why? well, seems the GeomFromText itself is interpreted as text :/
so I figured I'd try pushing pure WKB strings into the db instead, problem is I can't really figure out how to pack a WKT into WKB.

Could someone help me do this with this format description: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-wkb-format.html
and the doc for pack() over at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Grab a [specification](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.0/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm) and use "C" for bytes, "V" for uint32's and "d" for doubles in your `pack` format strings. However, my advice is not to do that. First, rewriting a build-in function is a waste of time. Second, transferring binary data with sql is error prone (think of encoding issues for example). And third, according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html you don't even need `GeomFromText`, because mysql already treats unquoted wkt as binary.

Comment: Thank you, however, removing GeomFromText is not helping me at the moment.


"INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon) VALUES (?, POLYGON((?,?,?,?,?,?)))"

triggers the following error:
"Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

any idea why this happens?

Comment: Seems this belongs in a question of its own, your answer is sufficient to the original qiestion =)

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems. First, the GeomFromText function takes a string, so it should look like `GeomFromText('POLYGON((0, 1, 2))')` (note the quotation marks). Second, since the `POLYGON...` text is a string literal, it should be replaced with the wildcard, not the individual pieces. Your query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon)
VALUES (?, GeomFromText(?))
```

You would then build the `POLYGON((?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))` string in the application, not in the statement. Since PHP has safe string handling I would recommend using `sprintf('POLYGON((%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d))', $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6)` (sprintf is dangerous in C).

Alternatively, you can use MySQL's spatial functions to generate the points. I think this is what you were trying to do, but you don't pass them through GeomFromText. To build a polygon with MySQL's spatial functions, the documentation suggests you would need to do:

```
INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon)
VALUES (?, Polygon(LineString(Point(?, ?), Point(?, ?), Point(?, ?))))
```

Prior to MySQL 5.1.35 you would need to do:

```
INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon)
VALUES (?, GeomFromWKB(Polygon(LineString(Point(?, ?), Point(?, ?), Point(?, ?)))))
```

Comment: cheers, Ive long since moved past this problem, can't even remember how I solved it but I'm pretty sure I reverted to individually escaping the values and building a query by concatenating strings.

any way, this answer is a good one and I would have tested it and accepted it if I had a chance to do that - so in the meantime it's an upvote from me, looks good and def someting I would have tried out with the problem at hand :)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed too late this was an old topic. I was trying to find information on PHP WKT handling and ended up answering an old question related to MySQL because this is the only question that showed up similar to what I was looking for.